# "Truth value of a series is ambiguous" - using Pandas nunique() to check whether there is only one unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check whether there is only one value in a column (while checking several columns), and I have written:

```
for c in df:
    
    if df[c].nunique() == 1:
```

..expecting this to evaluate to True or False based on a single coutn value returned by nunique()

However this gives an error:

"Truth value of a series is ambiguous"

I can't understand why the nunique does not just result in a single value, count of uniques, but somehow returns a series instead.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: This smells like an XY problem, what is the data looking like and what is the intended transformation? I.e., what would you do once you determined there was only 1 unique value

Comment: Indeed, this shouldn't do this, but please provide a reproducible example for us to ensure you don't have a typo/mistake and explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Also, have you done the obvious debugging step of checking the output of  `df[c].nunique()` at each step?